# How is the damage to items and the repair cost calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

While reparing your items was just a nuisance before patch 1.0.3, at least as long as you didn't die excessively, it is a very significant gold drain now. I'm trying to understand which factors affect the cost of repair and the amount of damage I have to repair.

- How exactly is the repair cost calculated. I understand it is connected to the ilevel of my equipment, but how does it work exactly.
- When are my items damaged and how much? The 10% on death are obvious, but for the non-death-related damage:

  - Is it based on how often I'm hit or on how much damage I take?
  - Do abilities that absorb or evade damage, e.g. diamond skin, also prevent damage to items?

Comment: No idea about the specifics, but armour takes damage when you take damage, and weapons take damage every time you hit an enemy with an attack.

Comment: Blizzard Community Managers have indicated on the forums within the past few days that they are looking into lowering the amount of normal wear & tear your gear takes from "Just Playing". This will likely be addressed in the next major patch, 1.0.4. 
Until then, the best alternative is to play in areas where you die very very little, or farm gold specifically for repairs, or pick up some extra gear with "Ignores Durability Loss". That prefix is now valueable, especially for Level 61+ items with high repair bills.

Comment: This is when http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/spaulders-of-zakara becomes very, very handy...

Comment: The repair costs increase depending on your item itself. more rare item will cost more to repair. The damage the items take is calculated using multiple factors.

Answer (score 1):

Diablo 3's durability formula is a pretty broad formula, and there isn't just one.

### Your equipment will lose durability when:

*You are in combat

You deal damage

You are hit

You die*

All three of these scenarios have different durability formulas that aren't actively released to the user. It would take someone that knows the code base to speak on it.

Dying causes you to lose the flat 10% like you said, but they also **have a chance** to lose durability based on how many times you are hit and not how much you are hit for. Like wise your gear **has a chance** to lose durability while you deal damage. This is called "stress" durability. If the gear is being used to negate or deal damage through its stats than the game considers the items to be "in use" and will passively lower the durability.

Low level items lose durability from stress much slower than higher level items do as well.

Based on the repair costs we know from World of Warcraft, it is safe to assume that repair costs in Diablo 3 are calculated in a similar manner. By using a flat rate based on the items rarity with additions for how much durability is lost from its total durability and a multiplier for its item level.

Blizzard seems to have copied much of their durability formula's from what they have created for World of Warcraft already. You can review them here:

[WoW durability guidelines](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Durability)